# A transform in Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have $x,y \in \mathbb{R_{++}}$. Given is that $\dot{x}=x(y-x-\ln(x)-1),   \dot{y}=1-x$.

Then we introduce a transform $z=y-\ln(x)$, where we must show that; $\dot{z}=2-z, \dot{y}=1-e^{y-z}$.

I know how to do the latter, i.e. rewrite $z=y-\ln(x)$ to $\ln(x) = y-z \rightarrow x=e^{y-z}$, which we 'plug' into $\dot{y}=1-x$ to get $\dot{y}=1-e^{y-z}$. But I do not know how to get $\dot{z}=2-z$, I tried plugging in $x=e^{y-z}$ but that didn't work out. Someone got any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Start by differentiating your transformation $z=y-\ln(x)$. You will get $\dot{z}=\dot{y}-\frac{\dot{x}}{x}$. Now plug in your expressions for $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ and simplify.

Comment: Thank you, I have got it now!